# Jquery Fade in & out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I have some code below showing my JQUERY & HTML. 
Basically I have tried to get an image to FADE IN on hover and FADE OUT once the cursor is off the image.

PROBLEM is that I want the image that will be FADING IN to be on top of the original image.
Once the new image FADES IN it goes back to the original straight away as the cursor is no longer on the image that executes the FADE animation.

I would appreciated any info what so ever :)

Thanks :)

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.hover").hover(

function() {
    $("div.fade").fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
    $("div.fade").fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hover"><img src="#"/></div>
<div class="fade"><img src="#"/> </div>
```

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if the way I have explained it all can be altered to increase my results of an answer :)

Comment: user can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to illustrate the problem ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder i have created one though i am not the op http://jsfiddle.net/bQrFb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the hover class on an element that contains both the image and the hover image, it will still be classed as "hovering" whichever image you hover over:

```
<div class="hover">
    <div><img src="#"/></div>
    <div class="fade"><img src="#"/> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are times that additional markup is worth it. This is one of those times. There's no reason to do this any other way! The fade code can be optimized further but in the end my optimizations would produce the same net results as Sohnee's suggestion plus the original... so it seems silly to go further. ;-)